# Remove HighCharts border for Android

Tags: android, highcharts

I'm trying to load a highchart js in an android webview and it works fine!

My webview is in a LinearLayout and I want the background of both layout to be the same color. But there is an undesirable white border around my chart that I can't remove.

I've set the chart background color in the js file and the linearlayout background color in the xml file.
I've tried to set an orange background color to the webview but I can't see it.
I've also tried to change the bordercolor and the bordersize attributes of the chart but the problem stay the same.
I don't know what to do now....

My layout goes like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#d6d7d4"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/chartView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/alarmList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And my js like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        backgroundColor: '#d6d7d4',

        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            year: '%Y'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'MW'
        },
        max: 500, 
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 100,
            color: 'rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.3)'
        }, { 
            from: 100,
            to: 200,
            color: 'rgba(215, 216, 212, 0.3)'
        }, { // Light breeze
            from: 200,
            to: 300,
            color: 'rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.3)'
        }, { // Light breeze
            from: 300,
            to: 400,
            color: 'rgba(215, 216, 212, 0.3)'
        },{
            from: 400,
            to: 500,
            color: 'rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.3)'
        }]
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.x) +': '+ this.y +' %';
        },
        valueDecimals: 1,
        valueSuffix: ' %'
    },
    series: 
    [{
        data: [[Date.UTC(2005, 1, 1),0],
            [Date.UTC(2008, 1, 1),10],
            [Date.UTC(2008, 1, 1),20],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 10, 1),30],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 10, 1),40],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 1),50],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 1),80]],
        type: 'line',
        color: "#504AA9"
    }]
});
```

});

And a screenshot of my android screen:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the background of the webpage might get rid of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/48wEc/

```
<body style="background-color:#d6d7d4;"> </body>
```

If not then it must be your webview making that boarder some how.